# View Stack, UIViewController, and Rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewcontroller that hosts a lot of Viewcontrollers. I set up autorotating on it and its subview and it works fine once the app has loaded. The problem I have is that during the initial loading process, the app has to connect and download some files locally. During this load if the user rotates the iPad the UIViewController doesn't rotate properly! I did set the flags and shouldautorotate but still not working.

PS : I am allowing these four orientations :

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
 }
```

After the load is complete the behavior is correct and rotates properly. Now I thought this could be because some of those inner VC's are loading some data, let me explain: 
The big View Controller hosts all other VC's ( Let's Call him BigDaddy), in the Viewdidload of bigdaddy I have (for argument sake ) three other ViewControllers : Busta, Skeezix, and lawrence. So I do:

```
[[Busta alloc] initWithNibName:@"Busta" bundle:nil];
```

and this in turn calls the `-viewDidLoad` of Busta, so I made the file loading section of that asynchronous by doing:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
```

Those changes did help a little bit, in the sense that before the async dispatch the load process would take 5 seconds (and in those seconds any tilt in the iPad would cause the rotation event and my whole view is gone. Now I got those 5 seconds down to 1.2 seconds. 
My question is, is there a solution to my problem? Will it never work? Is it possible to have an app rotate in four directions and respond to rotation changes while loading data?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with how you're doing your 'connect'.  I assume you mean you're connecting to a remote server using NSURLConnection or similar.  Be aware that if you use a synchronous connection on the main thread, you *will* freeze the app until the connection is finished.  The appropriate method is to utilize the asynchronous calls, or better yet move the work to a secondary thread (see NSOperationQueue documentation) and then move any updating of the UI based on that information back to the main thread (see again the NSOperationQueue documentation).

There is a good example for this in the WWDC 2012 videos.

Comment: Hi, I think this is the main issue, I am doing all my loading inside a  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    }); shouldn't that do it?

Comment: @Huang The problem is, you're still sending it to the main queue -- you need to create a secondary queue!  Because you're using 'dispatch_get_main_queue()', you never actually offload the work, you just delay it slightly.

Comment: hmm, well I am confused ( still new to objective C ) so I do create my own queue and sipatch on it, but now I get exceptions ,Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
Basically in this seperate queue I am creating uiwebviews and preloading them, then adding them to the main.view. so I

Comment: so I assume that the call to ad the webview to the UI needs to be performed on the main UI thread. How do I do that when I am not on the main queue??

Comment: @Huang This should give you a good starting point:  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBLock:<block>];

Answer (score 0):

Why not just implement your `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation...` method such that it allows rotation only after the app has finished loading the required data?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL appIsFinishedLoadingData = <your code here>
    return shouldRotate;
}
```

(I shortened your code in consideration of the fact that you're allowing all possible rotations, so there's really no need to check which rotation is being offered. Your way is more future-proof, mine is a little easier to read.)

Comment: hmm, well I tried this but for some erason it wouldn't work, right now I have - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if([self isLoading]) {
      return false;
   }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft etc etc 
}
 and when running on my iPad I hit the false branch under isloading, and return false, but still the iPad rotates!!

Comment: @Caleb this approach still runs into the critical issue that he's doing network work on the main thread -- this WILL cause the app to be rejected by Apple.  About the only way to get away with an app freezing for any length of time is to do it while the app is still loading, before it displays a UI of any sort.

Comment: @RonLugge Looks like I misread the question -- I was thinking that the OP wanted to avoid rotating until after the loading was done. Your point about freezing the main thread is a good one, but I think you overstated your case a bit. It's not so terrible to use the network from the main thread *provided* that you do it asynchronously with, for example, `+[NSURLConnection sendAsyncrhonousRequest...]`. But yes, you shouldn't do anything that causes the app to stop responding to the user or otherwise appear frozen.

Comment: @Caleb I may have mis-phrased my point.  To my mind, using an asynchronous network call automatically displaces you from the current thread.  I'm not sure if that's technically true behind the scenes or not, but that's how I tend to think of it.